# Auto Sizing text based on values-Word Frequency in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, word-frequency

I want to create a chart that is full of text. The text size should be based on values of the particular field.Example the data: a-10 b-20 c-15 means the the b text font size should be larger. i did this bu the problem is overlappin of data.. All i want is just the image shown.

![Word frequency chart for twitter][1]

Comment: A [word cloud](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud)?

Comment: Yes........ but now i got that . Any way Thanks for ur interest Lars.